# I get A "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in" when calling a static "setter" function from constractor

Tags: php, constructor, fatal-error, static-functions

I have a class. basically the construct and the setter function are the same.
everythings works great this way.
but when i try to delete the identical code from the construct function, and instead just call the setter function, i get a fatal error:
"Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in..."
here is the code before the change (this works fine without an error)

```
Class Zmanim extends ZmanimCalculation  {
//this class contains all the stuff needed in order to make the zmanim page work

private  $day_const,$month_const,$year_const,$latitude_const,$longitude_const,$tz_const,$date_convertor_const,$zmanim_array_const;



function __construct($set_day,$set_month,$set_year,$set_latitude,$set_longitude,$set_tz,$set_date_convertor=true) {

    $this->day_const=$set_day;
    $this->month_const=$set_month;
    $this->year_const=$set_year;
    $this->latitude_const=$set_latitude;
    $this->longitude_const=$set_longitude;
    $this->tz_const=$set_tz;
    $this->date_convertor_const=$set_date_convertor;

    $this->zmanim_array_const=ZmanimCalculation::Full_Zmanim_calculation ($this->day_const,$this->month_const,$this->year_const,$this->latitude_const,$this->longitude_const,$this->tz_const,$this->date_convertor_const);


}

static function setZmanim ($set_day,$set_month,$set_year,$set_latitude,$set_longitude,$set_tz,$set_date_convertor=true) {

    $this->day_const=$set_day;
    $this->month_const=$set_month;
    $this->year_const=$set_year;
    $this->latitude_const=$set_latitude;
    $this->longitude_const=$set_longitude;
    $this->tz_const=$set_tz;
    $this->date_convertor_const=$set_date_convertor;

    $this->zmanim_array_const=ZmanimCalculation::Full_Zmanim_calculation ($this->day_const,$this->month_const,$this->year_const,$this->latitude_const,$this->longitude_const,$this->tz_const,$this->date_convertor_const);
}
```

and this is how i call the construct(still works without an error:

```
$fullzmanim=new Zmanim ($_POST['zmanim_gregorian_day'],  
                        $_POST['zmanim_gregorian_month'], 
                        $_POST['zmanim_gregorian_year'], 
                        $latitude, 
                        $longitude, 
                        $tz);
```

but when i just call the setter static function within the construct function, i get an error. here is the bad code:

```
Class Zmanim extends ZmanimCalculation  {
//this class contains all the stuff needed in order to make the zmanim page work

private  $day_const,$month_const,$year_const,$latitude_const,$longitude_const,$tz_const,$date_convertor_const,$zmanim_array_const;



function __construct($set_day,$set_month,$set_year,$set_latitude,$set_longitude,$set_tz,$set_date_convertor=true) {
    self::setZmanim($set_day,$set_month,$set_year,$set_latitude,$set_longitude,$set_tz,$set_date_convertor);


}

static function setZmanim ($set_day,$set_month,$set_year,$set_latitude,$set_longitude,$set_tz,$set_date_convertor=true) {

    $this->day_const=$set_day;
    $this->month_const=$set_month;
    $this->year_const=$set_year;
    $this->latitude_const=$set_latitude;
    $this->longitude_const=$set_longitude;
    $this->tz_const=$set_tz;
    $this->date_convertor_const=$set_date_convertor;

    $this->zmanim_array_const=ZmanimCalculation::Full_Zmanim_calculation ($this->day_const,$this->month_const,$this->year_const,$this->latitude_const,$this->longitude_const,$this->tz_const,$this->date_convertor_const);
}
```

anybody know what is wrong?
thanks!

Comment: That's because static is not an object, not an instance of the class so you cant access `$this`, use `self` or `static` instead.  Of course this will also mean you cannot access non-static properties as well.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix That would require his class properties to be static, which aren't. Better would be to make the method non-static and call it regularly `$this->setZmanim(...);`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois - while I agree that all depends on why it was made static to begin with, you could also pass an instance of the class in to the method, but that is somewhat self defeating.

Comment: Why is your setter method static? I don't think you understand the meaning of static and what it does.

Comment: thanks guys. From now on my setters will *not* be static!